# How to add multiple values to existing keys for an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use `reduce()` for getting economy rate for a particular wicket.

Example data:

```
   var data = [
    {wicket:0, econ:20 },
    {wicket:1, econ:10 },
    {wicket:3, econ:45 },
    {wicket:0, econ:15 },
    {wicket:1, econ:32 }
]
```

I want `reduce()` method to return an array of objects which will look like this:

```
0: 20, 15
1: 10, 32
3: 45
```

What I am trying to do is initialize accumulator with object but in `reduce()` method I am not able to figure out how can I get the required array of objects with `key value` as `wicket`and `values` as `economy`.

My code:

```
const Economy = data.reduce( (a, {econ, wicket}) => {

            a[wicket].push(econ);           

    },{})
```

I get undefined behaviour with above code.

Comment: `reduce` is not a prototype method of Object. `data` is an object in your code above

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data` was meant to be an `Array` and not an `Object` (which it isn't right now, at least not a valid one) :

```js
let data = [
    {wicket:0, econ:20 },
    {wicket:1, econ:10 },
    {wicket:3, econ:45 },
    {wicket:0, econ:15 },
    {wicket:1, econ:32 }
];

let result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc[curr.wicket]) acc[curr.wicket].push(curr.econ);
  else acc[curr.wicket] = [curr.econ];
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use group the array using `reduce` like:

```js
var data = [{"wicket":0,"econ":20},{"wicket":1,"econ":10},{"wicket":3,"econ":45},{"wicket":0,"econ":15},{"wicket":1,"econ":32}];

var result = data.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.wicket] = c[v.wicket] || []; //Initiate the property as empty array of it does not exist
  c[v.wicket].push(v.econ);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

---

`||` is an OR operator.

This means if `c[v.wicket]` exist, it will assign it to `c[v.wicket]` again. If it does not, assign an empty array `[]`

```
c[v.wicket] = c[v.wicket] || [];
```

Comment: What does this line -> `c[v.wicket] || []` do ?

Comment: @stonerock Basically it initiates the property to an empty array of not exist.

Comment: But auccumulator is initialized as `{}` object so shouldn't it be `c[v.wicket] || {}`

Comment: @stonerock I added an explanation.

Comment: Yes, so lets say `wicket` is 0. it will check if `c[0]` exist. If it exist, assign the value

Comment: If not, assign an empty array so like `c[0] = []`